# how to avoid duplicated java doc for same method with different parameter

Tags: java, javadoc

as titled. I know we can use @see or @link, but if there any standard method to avoid it.
The example: two methods only differ on one parameter.

```
 /**
   * Enable Batching of single Point writes to speed up writes significant. If either actions or
   * flushDurations is reached first, a batchwrite is issued.
   * Note that batch processing needs to be explicitly stopped before the application is shutdown.
   * To do so call disableBatch().
   *
   * @param actions
   *            the number of actions to collect
   * @param flushDuration
   *            the time to wait at most.
   * @param flushDurationTimeUnit
   * @return the InfluxDB instance to be able to use it in a fluent manner.
   */
  public InfluxDB enableBatch(final int actions, final int flushDuration, final TimeUnit flushDurationTimeUnit);

  /**
   * Enable Batching of single Point writes to speed up writes significant. If either actions or
   * flushDurations is reached first, a batchwrite is issued.
   * Note that batch processing needs to be explicitly stopped before the application is shutdown.
   * To do so call disableBatch().
   *
   * @param actions
   *            the number of actions to collect
   * @param flushDuration
   *            the time to wait at most.
   * @param flushDurationTimeUnit
   * @param threadFactory
   * @return the InfluxDB instance to be able to use it in a fluent manner.
   */
  public InfluxDB enableBatch(final int actions, final int flushDuration, final TimeUnit flushDurationTimeUnit,
                              final ThreadFactory threadFactory);
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired end result?  Are you planning on using the javadoc tool to create HTML javadoc?

Comment: I wonder if these example should really have duplicated doc. The first method should explain how it creates threads, since it doesn't expect a `ThreadFactory` and the second one should explain how `ThreadFactory` is used. An empty `@param` list isn't helpful.